# Request client.guilds gives undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have not run into this problem before, because always messages or channels were passed on as arguments to my modules, but now I want to have an automatic, timed update. That means that no discord.js event triggers this code. I want to set a timer that triggers a function to add a role (roleID) in a specific guild (guildID)

```
role = await client.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id == guildID).roles.cache.find(role => role.id === roleID)
```

This code in particular gives me "undefined" for both client.guilds.cache.get() and .find() .
I have enabled presences and guild members in the app dev page and also announced those intents.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you know the guild, what do you need the `find` for?

Comment: Can you give the exact error that you got?

Comment: the .cache.find() is undefined, which means the error is something like "cannot find .roles of undefined". And I need the find/get function to get the guild object, because the function is not triggered by a discord event and therefore not passed on. The bot itself can be used in multiple guilds, so I need to specify which one. @Gh05d

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the index.js did not run as linearly as I thought. When I moved the code into the client.on("ready") callback function, it worked. That fixed my problem.